# Extract Array Gson to JSON

Tags: android, arrays, json, gson

I am using Gson to Json to extract JSON data  coming as response from back-end.

This is my sample response coming from server:

```
[{
    "name": "person name",
    "data": [{
        "phone": [
            "98153304",
            "18290304",
            "17226965"
        ],
        "other_details1 ": "other details",
        "other_details2": "other details"
    }]
}]
```

I am able to extract other details from the response by using

```
@SerializedName("other_details1")
@Expose
private String other_details;
```

and creating their getter and setter.

But I am not able to extract the Array coming in the response.

Can anyone please guide me how to extract Array in the Response using Gson to Json. If this format is not correct, please tel the same I'll communicate this to the back-end team.

Thank you

Comment: Format is correct how are you retriving

Comment: I am not able to retrieve the array  "phone" rest all the other details I am able to extract.

Comment: If I use datatypes such as Array or JsonArray then also it is of  no use. result is null.

Comment: Could you please paste the code snippet so that we can help better. FYI, phone is inside the data so you need to access the object inside another object to retrieve the value of phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
Gson gson = new Gson;
PersonModel jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonInput, PersonModel.class);
jsonObject.getPhone().get(0).getName();   //0 is position as per your content size give position
```

PersonModel.java

```
    public class PersonModel {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Datum> data = null;

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
    }

    }
```

Datum.java

```
    public class Datum {

    @SerializedName("phone")
    @Expose
    private List<String> phone = null;
    @SerializedName("other_details1 ")
    @Expose
    private String otherDetails1;
    @SerializedName("other_details2")
    @Expose
    private String otherDetails2;

    public List<String> getPhone() {
    return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(List<String> phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getOtherDetails1() {
    return otherDetails1;
    }

    public void setOtherDetails1(String otherDetails1) {
    this.otherDetails1 = otherDetails1;
    }

    public String getOtherDetails2() {
    return otherDetails2;
    }

    public void setOtherDetails2(String otherDetails2) {
    this.otherDetails2 = otherDetails2;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your Model/POJO class using [Jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Then you just need to access the getter/setter.

Check screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this approach.

Comment: Thank you for your time Sanat. I'll definitely let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Method to deserialize generic collection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

...

Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourClass>>(){}.getType();
List<YourClass> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

**((JSONObject)((JSONArray)((JSONObject)new JSONArray("your json string here").get(0)).get("data")).get(0)).get("other_details2");**

or iterate the json to get a Map and retrieve using values by simply passing the keys for specific arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your time Devender but SAM's solution already solved my problem.